# Create set with exclusion rules from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I would like to create groups from my data frame.
Teams with 1 in the corresponding row/column cannot stay in the same group.

How to create the largest groups and fond the minimum number of groups?

**Idea**

There are 5 teams (50 in the original dataframe) for some reason some teams have players in common. The data frame shows with 1 if two teams have a player in common if not, the cell is filled with nan.
How many and which teams can play together at the same time?

Here a sample data frame

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={'team1': [np.nan,1.0,1.0,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'team2':[1.0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'team3':[1.0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1.0],
                   'team4':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'team5':[np.nan,np.nan,1.0,np.nan,np.nan]}, orient='index',
                      columns=['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4', 'team5'])
```

|  | team1 | team2 | team3 | team4 | team5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 | NaN | NaN |
| team2 | 1.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| team3 | 1.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1.0 |
| team4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| team5 | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | NaN | NaN |

**Expected output**

In this easy case the minimum number pf groups is 2, and the possible solution is:

```
group1 = ['team1', 'team4', 'team5']
group2 = ['team2', 'team3']
```

Comment: Do you mean ```group2 = ['team3', 'team5']``` ?

Comment: First of all, all teams have common players with themselves, hence, the diagonal should be filled with 1:s. Secondly, could you explalin why ```team1``` and ```team3``` can be in the same group? First row (```team1```), third column (```team3```) has a 1, which means they have at least one common player. So, they should not be able to play against each other. If it is the point, then ```team4``` should not be in that group. I think that if you are more precise with how you form these groups, then the answer should be easy to codify. I like this problem, this is why I'd like to know.

Comment: sorry @SergedeGossondeVarennes, you are right. I created the groups quickly and didn't consider all the rules. I'll try to edit it again. About the diagonal your comment is right but if you have to check which teams can play with team1 you will never check if team1 can play with itself, won't you?

Answer (score 1):

Creating these groups is a combinatorial problem, and therefore not one you should try to solve using only pandas. One way of creating the groups is to model it as an assignment problem (for more information, see for instance https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/overview), which is what I tried below. As such, I introduce some additional technology, specifically ortools' CP-SAT solver.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


def solve(teams):
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    num_teams = len(teams)

    # Objective function: minimize Z, the total number of groups, which is an integer.
    # Incrementing Z amounts to creating a new group, with a new integer value.
    z = model.NewIntVar(1, num_teams, '')
    model.Minimize(z)

    # Create integer variables: one for each team, storing the integer representing the group to which that team belongs
    x = {}
    for i in range(num_teams):
        x[i] = model.NewIntVar(1, num_teams, '')

    # Constraint set 1: one constraint for each combination of teams that is not allowed to be in the same group
    idx = np.triu_indices(num_teams, k=1)
    for i, j in zip(*idx):
        if teams[i][j]:
            model.Add(x[i] != x[j])

    # Constraint 2: linking z, the group "counter", to our team variables
    for i in range(num_teams):
        model.Add(z - x[i] >= 0)

    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    status = solver.Solve(model)

    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        print(f"Total number of groups required: {solver.ObjectiveValue()}")

        for i in range(num_teams):
            print(f"Team {i + 1}'s group: {solver.Value(x[i])}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    team_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={'team1': [np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan],
                                             'team2': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                                             'team3': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0],
                                             'team4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                                             'team5': [np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan]}, orient='index',
                                       columns=['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4', 'team5'])

    team_data = team_data.fillna(0)
    solve(team_data.to_numpy())
```

Running this on the input data you provided produces:

```
Total number of groups required: 2.0
Team 1's group: 1
Team 2's group: 2
Team 3's group: 2
Team 4's group: 1
Team 5's group: 1
```

When I run this for 50 teams, with randomly generated constraints regarding which teams cannot join the same group, the solver finishes in 15 ~ 20 seconds. I don't know what your use case is, so I don't know whether this is acceptable for you.

Disclaimer: this solution will probably not scale well. If you need to tackle larger problem instances, you'll want a more sophisticated model. For help with that, you might consider posting somewhere like https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/, or you can do some more research by yourself.

I still decided to post my solution, since I think it's relatively easy to understand and can handle the size of problem you seem to be facing (at least if you're planning to run it offline).